# Cannot able to send Email on Django 1.10?

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem on sending mail on Django version 1.10 and the following erron can be appear in my console.

**Error**

```
   for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
```

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

**My code is,**

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'
DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "----------------"
        email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=['mymail@gmail.com'])
        email.send()
        print"--------------------stop"
        return render(request, 'contact/contact.html')
    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html')
```

Comment: your email account have IMAP is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Access for less secure apps? If not then,

Go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable this option.

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I have enabled this option, but the error doesnot clear, same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'e-mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

And and I would add this:

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

The latter will use the terminal to show your e-mails in text.

If you do not want to use the terminal to see your e-mails, rather send real e-mails, remove the `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable from your `Settings.py`.

Comment: It is not Worling dude.the following details can be printed in console---->>  MIME-Version: 1.0           
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"          
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit         
Subject: title        
From: webmaster@localhost      
To: mymail@gmail.com        
Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 10:18:02 -0000         
Message-ID: <20170224101802.14273.73327@admin-Lenovo-H50-50>            

body      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Remove the `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable from `Settings.py` and see what happens. Set the other variables like the ones I showed above.

Comment: gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known error can occurs when remove the EMAIL_BACKEND variable.

Comment: Well, so your problem seems to be something else. Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283550/i-got-error-hostname-name-or-service-not-known-when-checking-ip-of-hostname

Answer (score 0):

I think you have:

```
DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'mymail@gmail.com'
```

instead:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mymail@gmail.com'
```